# How can I create a reusable workflow which takes advantage of the attendees field in the OOTB calendar list?

Tags: workflow, calendar, reusable

I'm working on creating a workflow that sends notification emails to attendees involved in an event.

I switched my calendar to "Use this calendar to share member's schedule" mode, so that I get the "Attendees" column. However, when attempting to create a reusable workflow on the "Event" content type, there is no "Attendees" column. I edited the Event content type, adding an Attendees column, and created my email workflow, but this did not work.

I also created a list workflow on the calendar in question and that worked, but I am wondering if there is any way to create a reusable workflow to accomplish this? I have multiple calendars that I'd like to attach the workflow to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a calendar is used to share members' schedules, it switches from using the "Event" content type to the "Schedule" content type. After creating the workflow to leverage the Schedule content type, I was able to create the workflow as required!